# Steps to change SP_Farm account in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: managed-account, farm

In one of the SharePoint 2010 environment, sp_Farm account is responsible for the below services and we would like to change the password of the account.

```
Farm Account
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service
User Profile Synchronization Service
Web Analytics Data Processing Service
SharePoint Server Search
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Application Pool: SharePoint - 80
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Application Pool: SharePoint - 23692
Security Token Service Application
Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application
Search Administration Web Service for Search Service Application
Access Services
Secure Store Service
PerformancePoint Service Application
Visio Graphics Service
Managed Metadata Service
Word Automation Services
Excel Services Application
Business Data Connectivity Service
User Profile Service Application
Search Service Application
Web Analytics Service Application
```

Let me know if I could follow the steps and am I missing any steps?

**Change account password** 
Central Admin > Security > Configure Managed Accounts -> Click the Edit icon next to the account whose password you want to change -> Set account to new value -> SharePoint will change the password in AD and in SharePoint.

**UPS:**
Central Admin > System Settings > Manage Services on Server -> Stop the User Profile Service and let it do so.After it has stopped, click start to start it back up -> Supply that account when you start it back up.

**Windows services**
The same account is used for the Windows services? should we need to update the password or will it be taken care automatically?

Reboot the servers and check the status of the applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this on a regular basis and I always use this following PowerShell:

```
Set-SPManagedAccount -UseExistingPassword -Identity
```

I don't usually reboot but it never hurts. For identity, use the full login name.  After you hit enter, PowerShell will ask for the new password.  I find this a lot quicker than using the GUI.

Comment: does it mean that we need not to restart the UPS? and no updates are required on the SQL end..?

Comment: I haven't had to restart UPS in my experience and you do not need to update anything in SQL Server.  The PowerShell commandlet is basically the same as doing it through the GUI and handles all the necessary changes behind the scenes.  If you do run the command and notice things start misbehaving, just reboot your application server and everything should be ok.

Comment: The same account is used for the Windows services? should we need to update the password or will it be taken care automatically?

Comment: If by Windows services you are referring to the SharePoint related services that appear under services.msc, then yes, this change should update those also.

Comment: This shows to me: `"Missing an argument for parameter 'identity'. Specify a parameter of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPManagedAccountPipeBind' and try again.`